# Adaptive Subdivision Not 'Smartly' Subdividing Based on Camera Position

Tags: modeling

I set up Adaptive Subvision correctly (i.e. Cycles in experimental, displacement on in material settings, etc.) but it isn't dividing the plane I applied it to correctly (more subdivions closer to camera). I thought it's supposed to divide it based on the camera position, but it isn't, dividing the whole mesh the same way. What am I doing wrong?[image]
[image]

Comment: My guess: You're close enough to the mesh that there's no reason to adapt based on the density of subdivisions you've chosen.  Adaptive subdivision only helps dense meshes and then only if there's enough z depth to matter.  But you might want to add an example, at least screen shots, to show what you're doing.

Comment: Adaptive has viewport and render settings.  Might be worth checking, I don't know if anything has changed recently

Comment: Your picture doesn't demonstrate any problem.  Adaptive subdivision ends up only mattering in a rendered, Cycles view, as it subdivides for purposes of material displacement only, which only works in Cycles.  Additionally, it doesn't use any explicit camera; it uses your actual view, which may or may not be your camera.  If you think there is a problem after all that, consider linking a file.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the input.